# Jsch upload file with android to

Tags: android, file, upload, jsch

I want to upload file to our device using jsch.

I put the file in ecplise, in asserts folder..

```
JSch ssh = new JSch();
        JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session = ssh.getSession("host", "192.168.1.138", 22);
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftp.put("/assets/file.fl", "/ISGv2/file.fl");
```

But jsch cannot find the file... I try everything.. but cannot work..

I need help..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to make different class which extends AsyncTask.

2) put this code in doInBackground(...) method.

3) call this method with the help of `YourAsyncTaskExtendedclassName.execute();`

that's it !